# Rails acts_as_flying_saucer outside controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf-generation, flying-saucer, rufus-scheduler

I'm on a task where I need to create pdf's in a rufus-scheduler task but acts_as_flying_saucer does not work outside a controller.

The task I'm doing works fine in the controller but it's big and takes a long time and the worst part is that the user have to wait for the task to complete thus I need to put it inside a scheduler.

Any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

Which gem version you are using ? acts_as_flying_saucer can now works without rails controller.you can refer  [here](https://github.com/amardaxini/acts_as_flying_saucer)